# CUDA - My GPU (Quadro M2000M) is listed as CUDA compatible, but CUDA installation fails?

Tags: cuda, gpu, nvidia, theano

I'm running an NVIDIA Quadro M2000M on Windows 8.1. The GPU is listed as compatible (compute compatibility 5.0) on developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus , but when I try installing CUDA 7.5 (latest version), I get the error "Graphics driver could not find a compatible graphics hardware". Further, when I check the device list of 7.5, M2000M is not listed. I tried to hack the device in the .inf file, but got the same error. I tried installing it and running CUDA via theano on Python, but got the error message "cuda unavailable".

I tried rolling back to the older versions (6.0, 5.5, 5.0), but still recieved the same error. Anyone has any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something along the lines of "you can continue with the installation but CUDA applications will not work."

Comment: You might want to read the actual error message carefully, and think about it.

Comment: Sorry I am not in front of my system at the moment. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have the same GPU model, but in order to fix that kind of problems when trying to install CUDA on windows I proceed as follows:

1. Download and install the latest version of the [NVIDIA Drivers](http://www.nvidia.co.uk/Download/index.aspx) offering support for the intended GPU.
2. Execute the Local Installer for the CUDA version I need. In the wizard I deselect the options to install the video driver.
3. Set environment variables, cuDNN packages, etc.
4. Execute some tests.

According to the [Install Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/index.html#axzz4EWPSqIGC%20Install%20Guide) you can use the -s flag to perform subpackage installation. I normally just deselect the options I do not need in the install wizard, just as I described.

I hope that helps.

Comment: The cuDNN packages and the .theanorc.txt fixed this. Thanks.